# How to load multiple values for same key in property files?

Tags: properties-file

See this property file:

```
S=1
M=2 
[...]
IA=i 
S=g
```

First, the value `1` will be assigned to `S` and then `g` will be assigned to `S` in the last line.
I want to keep multiple values for the same key `S`, how can I do this?

Comment: The idea of a properties file is to have a univocal  correspondence between a key and a value. But if you really need it, perhaps what you could try to do is to have the values associated with key "S" separated by something: **S=1;g**. Then, when retrieving the values of "S", you'd need to take the separator into consideration.

Comment: I re-worded your question, to make it clearer and hopefully more attractive to people who know about this topic. I hope you agree with the edit!

Comment: @aribeiro thanx a lot for the reply. but i can't use separators like you mentioned because if i do that i have to do so many changes in the codes which have already written. so can you please suggest another way if you know?

Comment: @anderas yes i agree, thanx!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify whether this is a Java properties file or some other  file, as I've rarely seen it possible to define two separate "keys" with different values without some kind of a section break (ie .ini files).

The only other way I can think of for reading this type of file would be to pull it in as nested dict using the alphabet as the index (a-z, aa-az, etc), storing the key value pairs you've seen, so for example you'd have "a" = {S='1'}, "b" = {M='2'} [..] "z" = {S='g'} and then you could do a query for "letterKey" in dict "alpha" where key.value("innerKey") = 'S', which would give you both 'a' and 'z' due to the 'S' = '1' and 'g'. This may not be any easier than simply rewriting some of the existing code though.

Since a dictionary can't have multiple keys with the same "index" ie 'S' can't appear twice, if you could do as a commenter suggested and store two values in an array in 'S' and reference them via position S.value([0]) and S.value([1]), you'd have a much better program overall.